# problem in using pointer as a class member

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm trying to implement a school system, here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Studnet
    {
private:
        string Name;
        int Age;
        int ID;
public:
        Studnet(){};
        void setName(string name){Name =name;};
        string getName(){return Name;};
        void setAge(int age){Age =age;};
        int getAge(){return Age;};
        void setID(int id){ID =id;};
        int getID(){return ID;};
        ~Studnet(){};
    };
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class ClassRoom
    {
private:
        Studnet SetOfStudents[20];
        int flag;
public:
        ClassRoom(){flag=0;};
        void AddStudent(string , int , int);
        void DeleteStudent(int);
        void ListStudents();
        void ViewStudent();
        ~ClassRoom(){};
    };
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void ClassRoom::AddStudent(string name, int age, int id)
    {
        Studnet s;
        s.setName(name);
        s.setAge(age);
        s.setID(id);
        SetOfStudents[flag]=s;
        if(flag==20)
            {
            cout <<"This class is full"<<endl;
            return;
            }
            else
        {
        flag++;
        }
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*void ClassRoom::DeleteStudent(int pos)
    {
        for (int i = 19;i >=pos;i--)
            {
                if(i==pos)
                    {
                        delete SetOfStudents[i];
                    }
            }
    }*/
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void ClassRoom::ListStudents()
    {
        for (int i =0;i<2;i++)
            {
                cout<<SetOfStudents[i].getName()<< " " << endl;
            }
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void ClassRoom::ViewStudent()
    {
        cout<<SetOfStudents[0].getName()<<" "<<SetOfStudents[0].getAge()<<" "<<SetOfStudents[0].getID()<<endl;
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
    {
        ClassRoom c;
        for (int i =0;i < 2;i++)
      { 
        string Name;
        int ID, Age;
        cout << "Enter your name : ";
        cin >> Name;
        cout << "Enter your age : ";
        cin >> Age;
        cout << "Enter your id : ";
        cin >> ID;
        c.AddStudent(Name, Age,ID);
      }
      c.ListStudents();
      //c.DeleteStudent();
        return 0;
    }
```

so when I try declaring my set of students as a pointer

```
class ClassRoom
    {
private:
        Studnet *SetOfStudents[20];
        int flag;
```

the code runs normally but when I enter the first name and age and ID of the student it just close and the program ends, even though it should allow me to enter the second student information and print it
normal output

```
Enter your name : Hossam
Enter your age : 10
Enter your id : 10
Enter your name : Anas
Enter your age : 10
Enter your id : 10
Hossam
Anas
Press any key to continue . . .
```

wrong output

```
Enter your name : Hossam
Enter your age : 10
Enter your id : 10
and closses
```

Note: I've replaced each '.' operator with "->" arrow operator
Note: I tried declaring it like

```
Studnet *SetOfStudents= new Student [20];
```

and it didn't work
Note: don't mind DeleteStudent function its commented 
Note: The for loops are just for testing

Comment: this question is too long. please post a minimal example

Comment: 1) The thing about pointers, is that, they need to point to something. What do those pointers point to? 2) Why do you need pointers in the first place? In 99% of cases, where you think you need them - you don't, actually need them, in modern C++.

Comment: There is no reason to use pointers here. The original code using a fixed-size array is fine in that regard.

Comment: It looks like you've misspelled "Student" and "Studnet" everywhere and I can't not see it. You may want to fix that throughout your entire program. This may also be the reason that `Studnet *SetOfStudents= new Student [20];` isn't working (note that on the right there is the *one* time you've spelled Student correctly).

Comment: You will need to allocate each element of your array in some kind of loop: 'for(int n=0;n<20;n++) SetOfStudents[n] = new Student();' and then deallocate in destructor. Or better use smart pointer.

Comment: Why the mix of studnet and student? including your new student [20] being wrong...

Comment: @uneven_mark exactly what I wanted to add, but thats probably a homework assignment or a learning task

Comment: 1) This is just a learning task
2) I need pointer to delete elements from the array when I need to
3) thx for referring the wrongly spilled student, I'll fix that :)

Comment: @HossamMohammed If you are self-studying or as long as the teacher allows it, you should be using `std::vector<Student>` for `SetOfStudents`. Then you also wouldn't need `flag` and you would have dynamic size without any hassle. This is the proper way to handle arrays of dynamically varying size in C++. If you have stricter limitations on what you are allowed to use, then please add that to your question.

Comment: @HossamMohammed Break your bigger task into smaller parts and ask specific questions. I see that you put effort into solving this, but take a step back and try to understand everything that you do and test it on its own. Then, if there's something you don't figure out, you already have the [mcve] to post here and ask for help.

Comment: *"and it didn't work"* did you get a specific compiler error?